# How to add anchor tag to the img tag in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to include anchor tag inside img tag in html.

```
<img src="img.jpg" alt="no img" />
```

inside this i want to include:

```
<a onclick="retake();" > Retake </a>
```

Actually by clicking retake i want to take a different photo for that photo.

How to include a inside img? any help?

Comment: why do you need that.. when you can include `img` tag inside `<a>` tag `<a onlick="retake()"><img srd="img.jph" /></a>`

Comment: Have you tried putting the onclick event inside the img tag?

Answer (score 2):

An `img` element cannot contain *any* other content, whether HTML elements or even text-nodes. The closest you can come is to wrap the `img` with an `a`:

```
<a onclick="retake();"> Retake <img src="img.jpg" alt="no img" /></a>
```

Although there is the possibility to wrap the `img` with another element, say a `span`, and have the `a` as a sibling:

```
<span>
    <img src="img.jpg" alt="no img" />
    <a onclick="retake();"> Retake </a>
</span>
```

And use CSS to position it over the element (so visually-'within'):

```
span {
    position: relative;
}
span a {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/q8d58/).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the `<img/>` in the anchor:

```
<a onclick="retake();" title="Retake"><img src="img.jpg" alt="no img" /> Retake</a>
```

To swap the image on click:

```
function retake()
{
    this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src = "newimage.jpg";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the image tag like

```
<a onclick="retake();"> Retake <img src="img.jpg" alt="no img" /></a>
```

or you can put the image before text like

```
<a onclick="retake();"> <img src="img.jpg" alt="no img" /> Retake </a>
```